# python class variable annotation

Tags: python, annotations

I have a question concerning type annotations of class variables.

```
test: bool = "test"
```

the first line is not defined within a class and pycharm shows a warning that the type missmatches.

```
class test2:
    """t"""
    test: bool = "test"
```

now the same line within a class and pycharm says everything is correct. how does this work?

Comment: restart does nothing, it's the same behaviour

Comment: Actually, I just tried it and I don't get a warning either. I suspect that this is just a bug in Pycharm, because I don't see any reason why it should be allowing that. Maybe file a report with them.

Comment: Both are equally "wrong", but type annotations are not a very strict thing and IDEs don't really get them right always.